# Remove cross icon when open the fab-list

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi i want to do some custom styling in the ion-fab but didn't found anything to remove the cross-icon when we click and the fab button and the fab-list open, i don't want the cross icon 
[image]

So i want to get rid of this cross icon, moreover when i change the width and height it does not allow me to change its height in percentage. 
i.e

**allowed**

width: in percentage/pixels

height: pixels

**no-allowed**
 but required

height: percentage

```
 <ion-fab>
<ion-fab-button>
  <ion-icon name="share"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>

<ion-fab-list side="end">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab-list>
```

.css

```
ion-fab-button{
width: 75%;
height: 99px;
.button-native{
    .close-icon {

        display: none !important;
    }
}
}
ion-fab-list{
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
    width: 325%;
}
```

Please help me out in this.

Comment: the code you tried!!!    
Have you written any code for click event or `fab-list` open

Comment: its not about the click, its the css and i can show you my css if you need but its of no use

Comment: yes that will give me an idea of what you are trying

Comment: Though i found a class when i inspect the code in my browser i fount a class where i add "display:none" and the icon hides. The name of that class is  ".close-icon"

Comment: so you found solution

Comment: No i don't know how to add it in my css file because i am unable to access that class using css

Comment: ok post your code or make a https://codepen.io/

Comment: or is there any way i can access your app

Comment: https://codepen.io/babarkiani/pen/QXYdMz

Comment: here is my pen https://codepen.io/nick4434/pen/VJgPGM?editors=1100 you use it and edit as you have done it cause your pen is not working

Comment: actually i am using ionic native ion-fab button ,, your code is html i think

Answer (score 1):

You have limited control over this because the web components which Ionic 4 uses are self-contained.

Basically just because you can see it in the dev tools doesn't mean you can edit it.

You have to accept that you cannot control everything.

I'm pretty sure I just wasted my time trying to solve this for you because I cannot see myself ever using this particular skill again, haha... but this alllllmost does it:

```
ion-fab-button.fab-button-close-active {
     --color: var(--ion-color-primary);
     --transition: opacity 0 ease-in;
}
```

The only glitch is that when you click the button again to hide the X manages to show itself for a fraction of a second, and I couldn't find any combination to prevent it.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement a fab like functional icons? Like an horizontal accordion of icons maybe?

Comment: That's a different question. I don't know the answer, but if you really want to then I would start looking at the code of the fab-button-list in [Ionic Core](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/core/src/components/fab-list). You can pull out the code you want and make your own component?

Comment: I guess you need to decide if its worth all the effort to remove what seems to be a sensible ui element. Are you sure you want to prevent it being closed? It seems like its a bad way to go from the limited knowledge I have about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually i need functionality just like fab button, like when we tap on it, the icons open on the right and when i select any of them it becomes one button. But the fab is not the best way to achieve this for me because it has many problems.

Comment: yeah seems it might not be. I tried and then abandoned fab in my app as well. You might be able to get the styles out of it though that make the list fly out.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this:

```
ion-fab-button.fab-button-close-active {
  width: 16px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

With this, you can style the close icon in ion-fab.